# How to export static plots from Plotly in R using Orca?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have successfully installed Orca using Method 4 on the [github page](https://github.com/plotly/orca). However, I am unsure how best to proceed to export a static plot I have made in Plotly.

I have tried calling Orca in my R script using the syntax shown on the github page, but it returns "Error: The orca command-line utility is required to use the 'orca()' function".

I would appreciate if someone is able to explain the best way to proceed. I am inexperienced with the command-line, and do not understand the syntax shown for the command-line on the previously linked github page.

Comment: You don't say what you've tried, what has been "superseded", and what is over-complicated. Does `orca` from https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/ work?

Comment: Have updated to be more specific - thanks.

Comment: Assuming you also have `processx` installed, you might need to either (1) restart R, assuming you have added the `orca` command-line tool to your `PATH`; or (2) manually add its directory with something like `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0("/path/to/orcadir/;", Sys.getenv("PATH")))` and then trying again.

Comment: Option 1 worked for me - thank you